# Can I use both Python2 and Python3 to debug in PyCharm

Tags: python, pycharm

I'v already installed Python 3 on my windows, but recently I needed to use Python 2 for a project. I created a new environment in my anaconda, but in PyCharm I when wanted to debug the Python 2 code, a problem occured：

*(Connection to Python debugger failed
Socket operation on nonsocket: configure Blocking)*

I can only debug Python 3 code in pycharm in another environment, there's no problem, because Python 3 is in my windows path with a name Python (am I right?), and I add Python 2 to my windows path too, but I renamed it Python 2 not python to avoid the same path names. Is this the problem why pycharm can't recognize Python 2 and to debug my Python 2 code? If it is , how can I solve it to make pycharm can debug both Python 2 and Python 3. Or If it isn't , what's the problem? Thank you guys!!

Answer (score 0):

I am not a Pycharm expert, but i would do the following , uninstall all Python installations, Install first Python 2.x , create a virtual environment for my project with Python 2.X and then install Python 3.X and create a new virtual environment , from my experience you can have two different virtual environment  with different Python version